# How do I get an inclusive result set without using PHP?

Tags: mysql, expressionengine

Ok, so I've got this table called `exp_category_posts` that's in charge of storing the relationships between an `entry_id` and all it's associated `cat_id`s, as rows in the table (one column for `entry_id`, one column for `cat_id`)

For a search plugin I'm writing, a user can search by categories and I want to return all matching entries.

If I try to `SELECT entry_id FROM exp_category_posts WHERE cat_id = 1 AND cat_id = 2` I expect to get a set of entries that are assigned to both cats but instead I get an empty results set everytime.  Using `OR` does not give the results set I want.

The only way I've found to get the results I want is to break it into steps:

Step 1: Do a query for each cat_id.
Step 2: Save the result set as an array.
Step 3: Use a few `in_array()` calls to filter out the entries that aren't in all of the result sets.

While this method works, it's pretty inefficient.  Is there any way I can get the results I want with a single query instead of doing it this way?

Comment: Suppose `WHERE cat_id = 1` returns 1,2,3,4,5 and `WHERE cat_id = 2` returns 3,4,5,6,7.  The result I want to get is 3,4,5.  Using OR instead of AND would return 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    entry_id
FROM
    exp_category_posts
WHERE
    cat_id = 1 OR
    cat_id = 2
GROUP BY
    entry_id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Elegant solution.  Works slightly faster than JOINs when theres more than 2 cat_ids.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the intersection between two sets:

- `entry_id`'s that have `cat_id = 1`
- `entry_id`'s that have `cat_id = 2`

You can get that with `INNER JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT c1.entry_id
FROM
    exp_category_posts AS c1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT entry_id
        FROM exp_category_posts
        WHERE cat_id = 2
    ) AS c2
        ON c1.entry_id = c2.entry_id
WHERE c1.cat_id = 1
```

Comment: This approach isn't very easily generalised to intersections of more than 2 sets. If I want to find the intersection of `k` different sets, then using your method I need to join `k - 1` times, which is fairly awkward.